# How to use a variable in regex in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, string

There is a string (input from `stdin`), say `inputString`.

What I would like to do is match some regex that includes part of this variable string. For example, if input string is `stackoverflow`, I would like to match `stackoverflo[a-z]` or say `stack[a-z]overflow`(i.e. first 5 characters, some single character and rest of input).

How do I do this? I guess, probably I need to generate another string on runtime but not sure how I would do this.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want? Do you want to build a regex to match _any_ part of the `inputString` or the specific one?

Comment: Have a look at what [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) offer you for substring extraction, and string creation. Then come back to SO if you get stuck.

Comment: @hyst329 A specific part of string

Comment: So you really just want to know how to use strings?

Comment: @StoryTeller  Ok I will have a look

Comment: `std::string a = "hello"; std::string b = "world"; std::string c = a + " " + b;`

Comment: @Galik I don't know if regex provides ability to use strings or I have to first create strings myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just use normal [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) `insert`, `erase`, `substr`, concatenation....

```
std::string regex_string = inputString.substr(0, inputString.size() - 1) + "[a-z]";
...
string regex_string = inputString;
regex_string.insert(5, "[a-z]");
```

You'll have to decide how you work out the indices at which to copy, erase or insert.

Once you have the `regex_string` you want, just supply it to the [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/regex) library functions...

```
std::regex re(regex_string);
std::smatch match;
if (std::regex_search(my_string_to_match_against, match, re)) ...
```